# Add another regex to an existing one

Tags: regex, ng-pattern

I have the following 2 pattern :

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OdZaBe

```
 /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!#$%\-_=+<>])[A-Za-z\d!#$%\-_=+<>]/;
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ErLOOw

```
/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d!#$%\-_=+<>]/
```

pattern 1 require a letter/number/special character, and pattern 2 just a number and a character.

I would like to add to this a pattern that disable any whitespace or full whitespace string: `(?!\s*$)[\s\S]+$`

I tried

```
/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.\S*$)(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d!#$%\-_=+<>]/;
/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.(?!\s*$)[\s\S]+$)(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d!#$%\-_=+<>]/;
```

but it doesn't work has expected.

ENDING result would be

pattern 1 require at least 1 letter/number/special character and not allow any whitespace

pattern 2 require at least 1 number and character and not allow any whitespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both patterns do not match a whitespace by itself. See https://regex101.com/r/FaQhfD/1
 and https://regex101.com/r/IWWhSp/1

But in in your code you have to repeat the character class at the end using a quantifier and assert the end of the string unsing an anchor `$`:

```
$scope.thing = /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d!#$%\-_=+<>]+$/;
```

and:

```
$scope.thing = /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!#$%\-_=+<>])[A-Za-z\d!#$%\-_=+<>]+$/;
```

To prevent entering a whitespace at the end, you could use `ng-trim="false"`, see [ngTrim](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D):

```
<input type="text" ng-model="something" ng-pattern="thing" ng-trim="false" />
```

Example of the updated codepens: [update 1](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YBvKyw) and [update 2](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QYxLpx)